# Making separate urls for different pages of vue.js pagination

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, pagination

I made pagination using vue.js for the gallery on my website. However, whenever I access different pages, the URL does not change and when I refresh the page, it gets back to page 1. Instead, I would like to make it so when you are on page 3 for example, when you copy and paste the URL, you would get on to page 3.

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/np6fq9rv/) of how my gallery looks.

What I would like to do is add "?page={pageNum}" to the end of the URL, whenever I am on a specific page and when I enter that link, I would land on page {pageNum}.

I found a guide of how to that [here](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/pagination-nav/). I would like to implement the very first approach that is suggested on the website. Problem is that it looks like the supplied code is not full and I do not understant what I am supposed to do to make it work.

I have tried both adding the whole script tag and adding just the method inside the new Vue, in addition to adding :link-gen="linkGen" and use-router to the v-pagination tag, but that did not produce the expected result.

I would like to ask for help with implementing the feature to the provided jsfiddle.

Here is the code from the jsfiddle that I linked above:

```html
<div id="app" class="container text-center">
  <h1>
    Gallery
  </h1>
  <div v-show="currentPage == 1">
   <img class="w-25" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1499002238440-d264edd596ec?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80">
  </div>
    <div v-show="currentPage == 2">
   <img class="w-25" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1499002238440-d264edd596ec?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80">
   <img class="w-25" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1499002238440-d264edd596ec?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80">
  </div>
    <div v-show="currentPage == 3">
   <img class="w-25" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1499002238440-d264edd596ec?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80">
   <img class="w-25" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1499002238440-d264edd596ec?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80">
   <img class="w-25" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1499002238440-d264edd596ec?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80">
  </div>
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-center mt-3">
    <v-pagination
      v-model="currentPage"
      :page-count="totalPageCount"
      :classes="bootstrapPaginationClasses"
    ></v-pagination>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="js/lightbox-plus-jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js'></script>
<script src='https://unpkg.com/vue-plain-pagination@0.2.1/dist/vue-plain-pagination.umd.min.js'></script>
<script>
    new Vue({
      components: {
        vPagination: window['vue-plain-pagination'] },

      data: {
        currentPage: 1,
        totalPageCount: 3,
        bootstrapPaginationClasses: {
          ul: 'pagination',
          li: 'page-item',
          liActive: 'active',
          liDisable: 'disabled',
          button: 'page-link' },

        customLabels: {
          first: false,
          prev: 'Previous',
          next: 'Next',
          last: false } } }).


    $mount('#app');
</script>
```

Bump. Still unable to add the feature to my website.

Answer (score 1):

https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#reacting-to-params-changes is the way to go.

1. Set up vue router
2. Create a dynamic route
3. Set up vue watcher for $route in order to be go to the correct page via url (extract page number from url and set it accordingly in your component)